# What "feature flag" is causing these "errors" to be called out in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

[image: Below is a picture of one of the errors]

I'm the only one on the team using VSCode seeing these and it's a very helpful thing that I would like to help everyone take advantage of, but I can't seem to find why they show up for me and no one else.

[image: The responsible part of reporting the error is pyLance which we are all using]
But it doesn't flag anything for them, and it does for me.  How do I trackdown what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is coming from the Pylance extension, you can see it in the message. To disable/enable the message go to

1. Settings (UI)
2. Search for "python type checking"
3. Choose between **off**, **basic** or **strict**

[image: search results for python type checking]